# JavaScript: how to sum values of variables and display as div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new user at JS and I am trying to sum 2 values from HTML input.

The problem:
I have 3 HTML input's:

- Input by `type=number` (select number from input field);
- 2 inputs with `type=radio`

I want to sum the value of the `number` field with value of the selected `radio` button in real time (using jQuery).

JS:

```
$('#quantity').click(function () {
    $('#sum').text($(this).val());
});

$('#y').click(function () {
    var y = document.querySelector('#y').value;
    $('#sum').text($(this).val()).y;
}); 

$('#x').click(function () {
    var x = document.querySelector('#x').value;
    $('#sum').text($(this).val()).x;
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input id="quantity" type="number">
    <input id="y" name="math" type="radio" value="0">
    <input id="x" name="math" type="radio" value="1">
</form>
<span id="sum"></span>
```

I just want to add the value of the selected `radio` input to the value in the "quantity" field.

Example: If the value of the "quantity" field is "100" and I click on the "x" radio button (value = 1), then print "101".

Comment: `x` and `y` are not jQuery properties, you want `$("#sum").text($(this).val()+x);`. Also, use `getElementById` instead of `querySelector` when you are grabbing just an ID. Also, you can use `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()` since it appears you're mixing native DOM and jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```js
// Any time this is edited, update
$('#quantity').on("input", function() {
  $('#sum').text(sumThem() );
});

// ANY radio button with the name math
//  gets clicked, we do this ONE function.
$('[name=math]').click(function() {
  $('#sum').text(sumThem() );
});

function sumThem(){
  var qty = parseInt($("#quantity").val()) || 0;
  var addend = parseInt($("[name=math]:checked").val()) || 0;
  
  return qty + addend;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="quantity" type="number">
  <input id="y" name="math" type="radio" value="0">
  <input id="x" name="math" type="radio" value="1">
</form>
<span id="sum"></span>
```

There were a couple small problems: First, when the text input was updated, it wasn't adding in the radio button. Second, if no radio button was clicked, it was giving a NaN issue. Now, when you input on the text, if there's no radio clicked, the value is set to 0.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But there is one mistake: if firstly I click on radio (not on input=number), system prints "NaN". @Snowmonkey

Comment: That should be fixed. By moving the sum to a separate function, both actions will function exactly the same. And error checking are your friend.

Comment: Thank you, it works. And finally I need one more thing: if I firstly select radio button and then key up on input=number, need to uncheck radio button for safety reasons. I tried to add this line: `$("#y").checked = false;` @Snowmonkey

Comment: Ok, I just fixed with this line: `document.getElementById('y').checked = false;` It is ok to embed this code into jQuery?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "embed this into jQuery, you might simply want to save this into one of your external js files and load it along with whatever other scripts you do.

Answer (score 2):

Add an `id` to your form (I used `myForm` here for example) and then try something along these lines:

```
$('#myForm input').change(function() {
  var quantityVal = +$('#quantity').val();
  var radioVal = +$('[name="math"]:checked').val();
  var sum = quantityVal + radioVal;
  $('#sum').text(sum)
});
```

Here we're adding a change listener to all the inputs in the form, so that if any of them change in any way (not click like you had) the function will run. We then use jQuery to grab the value from the quantity input as well as the radio which is `checked`. You'll notice we also use [unary +](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) for both to make sure they are cast to integers.

Finally we just set the value of the `sum` span. The above should get you most of the way there, though you should probably add some error checking for empty radio values (or set a default one).

[Live example here](http://codepen.io/pabs123/pen/mRpKrm)

Comment: You'd better `parseInt()` those values or our you're going to get some funky string concatenations.   ;)

Comment: How do you figure? they're already being converted using the unary plus on lines 2 and 3

Comment: Oh shoot!  My bad . . . I didn't see them (they are so small!   :D   ).  Nicely done.